# Max total in Excel

Tags: excel, max, vlookup

I have 2 excel spreadsheets : the first one is: ID Name The second is: ID Name Price

The first table contains partial ID from the range in the second (2-full range, 1-part of the ID's). How can I find on the first spreadsheet the largest total amounts of deal per ID?

I guess I should use the VLOOKUP ,but I hadnt find it yet.

Comment: `=MAXIFS(priceRange, id, idRange)`

Comment: I dont know the id that I need, I want to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

as @jsheeran mentioned you can use  MAXIF if you are using EXCEL 2016 .
But for  older version you need to use Array  formulas:
A good example here:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28589900/A-MAXIFS-function-in-Excel.html

and  linked file:
https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2015/01_w01/890661/MAXIF-number-2.xlsx

Comment: I dont know the ID that have the TOTAL MAX  ,  I mean on one spreadshit I have the IDS and amounts, and on the other spreadshit I have Just the ID .
What you seuggested is fot the case when I know the ID.

Comment: https://ibb.co/i0hxuk

As you can see there are 2 spreadsheets .
The left is all the ID's with their payments , and on the right side there is a sheet with Partial client .
I want from the right sheet find the ID on the left side that his total payments are the maximum .

Comment: That's better!.have you tried using Pivot table? or  it is not what you looking for?

Comment: It doesnt give me what I want.

Comment: It seems that you need to do 3 steps
1- Find  the max  value  for  every person (using maxif  or pivot van  do that)

2- in IDS sheet concatenate name and payment in another  column
and copy id to another  column after above  column

3- use  vlookup  to  find that id  ,  for example  new  vlookup will look  for "JOHN3000" in IDS worksheet

Answer (score 0):

The Q is obscure but the image of a data sample (provided in a Comment) indicates that a PivotTable would suit:

[image: SO45273778 example]

It has been filtered Top 10 to select the three highest values by ID for Sum of Payment.